# MySQL select with group and one to many relations condition

Tags: mysql

For example have such structure:

```
CREATE TABLE clicks
    (`date` varchar(50), `sum` int, `id` int)
;
CREATE TABLE marks
    (`click_id` int, `name` varchar(50), `value` varchar(50))
;
```

where click can have many marks

So example data:

```
INSERT INTO clicks
    (`sum`, `id`, `date`)
VALUES
    (100, 1, '2017-01-01'),
    (200, 2, '2017-01-01')
    ;
INSERT INTO marks
    (`click_id`, `name`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 'utm_source', 'test_source1'),
    (1, 'utm_medium', 'test_medium1'),
    (1, 'utm_term', 'test_term1'),
    (2, 'utm_source', 'test_source1'),
    (2, 'utm_medium', 'test_medium1')
    ;
```

I need to get agregated values of click grouped by `date` which contains all of selected values.
I make request:

```
select 
  c.date,
  sum(c.sum)
from clicks as c
left join marks as m ON m.click_id = c.id
where 
(m.name = 'utm_source' AND m.value='test_source1') OR
(m.name = 'utm_medium' AND m.value='test_medium1') OR
(m.name = 'utm_term' AND m.value='test_term1')
group by date
```

and get 2017-01-01 = 700, but I want to get 100 which means that only click 1 has all of marks.
Or if condition will be

```
(m.name = 'utm_source' AND m.value='test_source1') OR
(m.name = 'utm_medium' AND m.value='test_medium1')
```

I need to get 300 instead of 600

I found answer in getting distinct click_id by first query and then sum and group by date with condition whereIn, but on real database which is very large and has id as uuid this request executes extrimely slow. Any advices how to get it work propely?

Comment: Joining the tables will produce the tuples:
`clicks (100, 1, '2017-01-01') marks (1, 'utm_source', 'test_source1') ;
clicks (100, 1, '2017-01-01') marks (1, 'utm_medium', 'test_medium1') ;
clicks (100, 1, '2017-01-01') marks (1, 'utm_term', 'test_term1') ;
clicks (200, 2, '2017-01-01') marks (2, 'utm_source', 'test_source1') ;
clicks (200, 2, '2017-01-01') marks (2, 'utm_medium', 'test_medium1')`

All of them matches your where clause, that's why you are getting 700.

Question: can a click contains the same mark more than once?

Comment: No clicks to marks has relation one to many so one click - many relations

Comment: To clarify: wy question is if you can have something like this on marks table: (1, 'utm_source', 'test_source1'),
(1, 'utm_medium', 'test_medium1'),
(1, 'utm_term', 'test_term1'),
(1, 'utm_term', 'test_term1')
Note that you would have  'utm_term'/'test_term1' twice for click 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using below queries:
When there are the three conditions then you have to pass the `HAVING count(*) >= 3`

```
SELECT cc.DATE
    ,sum(cc.sum)
FROM clicks AS cc
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM clicks AS c
    LEFT JOIN marks AS m ON m.click_id = c.id
    WHERE (
            m.NAME = 'utm_source'
            AND m.value = 'test_source1'
            )
        OR (
            m.NAME = 'utm_medium'
            AND m.value = 'test_medium1'
            )
        OR (
            m.NAME = 'utm_term'
            AND m.value = 'test_term1'
            )
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING count(*) >= 3
    ) AS t ON cc.id = t.id
GROUP BY cc.DATE
```

When there are the three conditions then you have to pass the `HAVING count(*) >= 2`

```
SELECT cc.DATE
    ,sum(cc.sum)
FROM clicks AS cc
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM clicks AS c
    LEFT JOIN marks AS m ON m.click_id = c.id
    WHERE (
            m.NAME = 'utm_source'
            AND m.value = 'test_source1'
            )
        OR (
            m.NAME = 'utm_medium'
            AND m.value = 'test_medium1'
            )
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING count(*) >= 2
    ) AS t ON cc.id = t.id
GROUP BY cc.DATE
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe571a/35

Hope this works for you...

Comment: So corect me if I'm wrong:
If I have 350000 clicks which have marks, so quere will execute 350000 subqueries?

Real DB has mode then 1 000 000 clicks and about 1 500 000 marks

Comment: It will work only if you don't have more than one marks with the same name and value for the same click. Anyway if that's the case it's straightforward to adapt the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 700 because the join generates multiple rows for the different IDs. There are 3 rows in the `mark` table with `ID=1` and `sum=100` and there are two rows with `ID=2` and `sum=200`. On doing the [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) where shall have 3  rows with sum=100 and 2 rows with sum=200, so adding these sum gives 700. To fix this you have to aggregate on the click_id too as illustrated below:

```
select 
  c.date,
  sum(c.sum)
from clicks as c
inner join (select * from marks where (name = 'utm_source' AND     
    value='test_source1') OR (name = 'utm_medium' AND value='test_medium1')  
    OR (name = 'utm_term' AND value='test_term1')
    group by click_id) as m
ON m.click_id = c.id
group by c.date;
```

**[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c50ad/8)**

Comment: doesnt work. It returns 300 even if all 3 conditions are set, but must return 100

Comment: Thanx for direction, i've found solutiopn

Answer (score 1):

I found the right way myself, which works on large amounts of data
The main goal is to make request generate one table with subqueries(conditions) which do not depend on amount of data in results, so the best way is:

```
select 
  c.date,
  sum(c.sum)
from clicks as c
join marks as m1 ON m1.click_id = c.id
join marks as m2 ON m2.click_id = c.id
join marks as m3 ON m3.click_id = c.id
where 
(m1.name = 'utm_source' AND m1.value='test_source1') AND
(m2.name = 'utm_medium' AND m2.value='test_medium1') AND
(m3.name = 'utm_term' AND m3.value='test_term1')
group by date
```

So we need to make as many joins as many conditions we have